# Flutter release apk is not installing on device

Tags: flutter, apk, release, flutter-apk, flutter-release

I have release apk with signed keys but it's not installing on android devices, its shows this message "**The apk failed to install
Error: Could not parse error string"** but debugging mode apk, the app works fine.

release command

flutter build apk --release.

I did follow this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054291/cant-build-release-apk-for-flutter?rq=1) to solve it, hope it helps someone.

Comment: did you follow instructions on [Preparing an Android App for Release](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android) ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65855995/1318946

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're trying to install a signed APK after using a debugging mode APK, Android will detect differences in signature, and refuse to install it.

Make sure you've uninstalled the unsigned debugging APK first from the device, and try to install again.

Comment: Please  l tried that but still not working. Error  "The apk failed to install Error: Could not parse error string"

Comment: Couple different things it could be. What's your Android's API version?

Comment: One thing to try for more information is try to install the generated APK using adb: `adb install your-app.apk` and see if that installs or gives an error

Comment: API version  minSdkVersion 16, targetSdkVersion 28 , release apk still not installing .

Comment: Yes this will work. i tried it

Answer (score 0):

Please check available disk space on the target Android Device before doing any actions.
For most of cases it is a due to insuffisant space on the device.