# Flutter crash on release apk installed on devices / Emulator

Tags: flutter

Could you guys please help me with the problems I currently have?
I'm trying to follow the steps of how to release apk android from: https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android, The program which I tried to release is only the NewFlutterApplication which created from template of Flutter

The problem is: Have been followed all the steps, still I can't run the release apk which i build from flutter

The Error which I got:

```
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install E:\FlutterProject\flutter_app_1\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]
Install failed
```

The things that I have tried:

- Tried from this site [Flutter release apk is not installing on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56464704/flutter-release-apk-is-not-installing-on-device), but there is no hope
- Tried from this site [Can't build release APK for flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054291/cant-build-release-apk-for-flutter?rq=1), but still no hope
- Tried using the flutter run --release in the real device, it's directly crash and return stopped working
- Tried using the flutter build apk && flutter install, it's not running and give the error from top error

Tried using flutter run -v it don't give any error and run smoothly and the debug it's still run smoothly, only the release APK is the problem which can't be run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPD: This answer is outdated, Flutter now supports x86/x64**

You can't run release build on emulator, because currently flutter doesn't support x86 release binaries

See this issue, and put thumb up reaction on it to increase priority:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9253

This issue also affects devices that use Intel Atom and some Chromebooks, but don't worry, they will be excluded from supported devices by Google Play automatically

Comment: so how to test the release apps? is it possible to run in the real device? but when I tried in real device it's directly give me crash apps

Comment: @JEFF I'm building two separate apk for amr and arm64, use `--target-platform=android-arm` and test it on real device

Comment: is it needed to put anything in the `defaultConfig` in the **build.gradle**? for example `ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'armeabi' //'x86',
        }`

Comment: @JEFF depends, if you put it, it won't hurt anyway

Comment: is it possible to link the Run tab to the device itself? i cant figure out the prob in my case, the screen is blank in release mode but works fine in debug mode.

Comment: @chitgoks x86 is now officially supported and your case might be a flutter issue, report it

Comment: @DimaRostopira my isos are x86 but there does not seem to be any option in android studio that can deploy the app to emulator as release. my problem is a data issue though, i got to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

`INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS` is when you are trying to install an app that has native libraries and it doesn't have a native library for your cpu architecture. For example if you compiled an app for armv7 and are trying to install it on an emulator that uses the Intel architecture instead it will not work.