# (React-Native 0.62.0) Getting Unable to find a matching variant of project :react-native-community_async-storage (same for other libs too)

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

My project was working perfectly but it stops building after upgrading to RN 0.62.0 from RN 0.59.5 (**debug build is working fine, it happens only for assembleRelease**)

I did some research and came across using [macthingFallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44218614/gradle-4-0-unable-to-find-a-matching-configuration/44510504), but that doesn't worked too.

[missingDimensionStrategy](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/issues/2150) can be a solution, but adding it for every library used can't be optimised option.

My **android/app/build.gradle** have

1. Two items in signingConfigs i.e. prod and stage that contains info
   about .keystore
2. Four items in productFlavors (i.e. dev, beta, prod,
   qa)
3. Three items in buildTypes i.e.

> ```
>    debug {
>         applicationIdSuffix = ".dev"
>     }
> ```

```
release {
    minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    productFlavors.beta.signingConfig signingConfigs.stage
    productFlavors.prod.signingConfig signingConfigs.prod
    productFlavors.qa.signingConfig signingConfigs.stage
    matchingFallbacks = ['release']
}
packagingOptions {
    pickFirst "lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so"
    pickFirst "lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so"
    pickFirst "lib/x86/libc++_shared.so"
    pickFirst "lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so"
}
```

**android/build.gradle** have

```
dependencies{
   classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3')
}

repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

my **gradle-wrapper.properties** have

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.0.1-all.zip
```

my **gradle.properties**

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

FLIPPER_VERSION=0.33.1
```

**settings.gradle**  have

```
rootProject.name = 'APPNAME'

include ':react-native-config'
project(':react-native-config').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-config/android')


apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)

include ':react-native-sound'
project(':react-native-sound').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-sound/android')

include ':app', ':react-native-code-push'
project(':react-native-code-push').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app')
```

[Error logs after running ./gradlew assembleRelease](https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.bd2bd84b1b6e41eca0f7e8dc272d6bc6&right=local.zerima) (giving error only for release build)

Comment: first of all, ios or android? or both?

Comment: oops forget to mention, it is android only

Comment: In case my answer doesn't help, downgrade your version to 0.61.5, it should work.

Comment: sure, I will wait for sometime. Else will try some higher or lower RN version

Answer (score 0):

Using the README.md of the [async-storage](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage) itself, you can install the library as follow:

If you're using yarn:

```
yarn add @react-native-community/async-storage
```

If you're using npm:

```
npm install --save @react-native-community/async-storage
```

Then:

```
npx jetify
```

Then run your project again

In case this doesn't work, try:

```
react-native link @react-native-community/async-storage
```

Then recompile your app again

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it is happening for every native npm used. And I think we don't need to use link command after RN 0.60.0

Comment: Yeah, because Async storage supports auto-linking, but the newer versions of react-native it's kinda buggy. 
And if you migrate from 0.59 to 0.60+, so much things changed.
Hope you find a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Without any success and searching over internet, I came across [similar problem faced by someone with flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054291/cant-build-release-apk-for-flutter) and from there I added following lines in my android/app/build.gradle within android section

```
lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
```

Now it is working fine in release as well as debug mode. (it might introduces some bugs, let's see)